# Como consigo filtrar as primeiras ocorrências de uma determinada variável no meu data frame em R?

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com todas as UF´s do Brasil:

```
date <- c("03/06/2020", "03/06/2020", "05/06/2020", "06/06/2020", "07/06/2020")
uf <- c("RJ", "SP", "RJ", "SP", "RJ")
confirmed <- c("0", "1", "1", "2", "3")
df <- data.frame(date, uf, confirmed)
```

Como consigo filtrar as primeiras ocorrências de uma determinada variável no meu `data.frame` em R?

Comment: *"filtrar"* significa que quer ficar só com as primeiras ocorrências ou removê-las? E *"determinada variável"* é qual das três? A pergunta está muito pouco clara e, devido a isso, já com dois votos para fechar.

Comment: Significa que quero ficar somente com as primeiras ocorrências. Determinada variável se aplica a "confirmed", já que não é trivial querer as primeiras ocorrências sendo UF's. Pense como sendo casos de doença confirmados em cada UF ao longo do tempo, quero achar as datas das primeiras ocorrências. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solução `dplyr` obtém as datas dos primeiros casos confirmados por `"uf"`.
Primeiro transformam-se as datas em classe `"Date"` e `confirmed` em classe `"numeric"`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y"),
         confirmed = as.numeric(as.character(confirmed)))
```

Agora obtém-se uma base das primeiras ocorrências de casos confirmados.

```
prim_conf <- df %>%
  filter(confirmed > 0) %>%
  group_by(uf) %>%
  summarise(date = first(date)) 

prim_conf
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  uf    date      
#  <chr> <date>    
#1 RJ    2020-06-05
#2 SP    2020-06-03
```

Se se quiser também quantos casos confirmados houve a essas datas, um *join* com a base original vai buscar esses valores.

```
prim_conf %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("date", "uf"))
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  uf    date       confirmed
#  <chr> <date>         <dbl>
#1 RJ    2020-06-05         1
#2 SP    2020-06-03         1
```

Ou, mais simplesmente, sem desagrupar a base,

```
prim_conf %>% left_join(df, by = c("date", "uf"))
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  uf    date       confirmed
#  <chr> <date>         <dbl>
#1 RJ    2020-06-05         1
#2 SP    2020-06-03         1
```

Answer (score 0):

O [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) tem um função muito útil para isso: `first()`. Você pode usá-la para retornar a primeira ocorrência de um vetor.

Combinando-a com `group_by()` podemos chegar a uma solução para o problema:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(uf) %>% 
  summarise(data_inicio = first(date))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   uf    data_inicio
#>   <fct> <fct>      
#> 1 RJ    03/06/2020 
#> 2 SP    03/06/2020
```

Se esse comando permite retornar o primeiro valor, podemos usá-lo em `filter()` para filtrar as observações desejadas.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(uf) %>% 
  filter(date == first(date))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   uf [2]
#>   date       uf    confirmed
#>   <fct>      <fct> <fct>    
#> 1 03/06/2020 RJ    0        
#> 2 03/06/2020 SP    1
```